# Scheme::R5RS. I'm studying lambda and I don't understand these codes

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, racket, r5rs

```
I'm studying lambda for my midterm and I understand the concept. 

**the lambda function is just a way of defining a function without giving it a name.
**the lambda format has to be ((lambda (x y z) (formula) parameter)
**please fix me if I'm wrong.

I don't understand the codes below.
Can someone explain to me why the answer is like that?
I know it's a lot, you don't have to explain all the examples.
Thanks!
```

```
((lambda (x y z)(x(/ y 2)(* 3 z)6))+ 4 2)                   ;14
((lambda (x)((lambda (x)(/ x 4))(+ x 2)))6)                 ;2
((lambda (x y)(+ (x * y)(x + y)))(lambda (x y)(x y y ))3)   ;15
(((lambda (a)(lambda (b) '(lambda (c) '(a b c)))) 1) 2)
(((lambda(x)(lambda(y)(+ x y))) 12) ((lambda(z)(* 3 z)) 3))
(define (x y z)((lambda (y z)(- y z)) z y)) (x 3 5)
((lambda (x y) (+ 3 x (* 2 y))) (+ 3 3)(* 2 2))
((lambda(x)(lambda(y)(+ x y)))12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily rewrite a `lambda` to a `let`. Eg.

```
((lambda (x y z)
   (x (/ y 2)
      (* 3 z)
      6))
 + 
 4 
 2)
```

As let:

```
(let ((x +) (y 4) (z 2))
  (x (/ y 2)
     (* 3 z)
     6))
```

It is the exact same code but perhaps slightly more readable. Every `lambda` for that gets called immediately can get that treatment also after substitution steps. 
Now you can use the substitution rules. Replace `x` with `+`, `y` with `4` and `z` with `2` and replace the call/`let` with the same expression with the values replaced:

```
(+ (/ 4 2)
   (* 3 2)
   6))
```

Substitute simple expressions with their result:

```
(+ 2
   6
   6))
; ==> 14
```

And there you go. Easy peasy.